# Calculate insersection from arrays using & operator

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, operator-keyword

I am taking number of array and I want to calculate insersection from arrays using `&` operator but in my case after calculate intersection `str1 & str` in `str1` array, but `str1` is empty.

```
n = gets.strip.to_i
str1 = Array.new
str2 = Array.new
for i in 0..n-1 do
  str = gets.strip.split("").map { |s| s.to_s }
  if i < 1
    str1 << str
    #puts str1.kind_of?(Array)
    #puts str.kind_of?(Array)
  else
    #puts str1 
    #puts "no"
    #puts str
    str1 = str1 & str
    puts str1
  end
end
puts str1.length
```

Comment: You are writing program to find out which characters appear in _all_ entered strings, right? Why haven't you stated so?

Comment: Hi, use this link to imporve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 << str
```

appends array `str` to array `str1` (so you get something like `['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e', 'f']]`). You want assignment instead:

```
str1 = str
```